Accessing and modifying Array elements
int arr [] {};
cout << "The 1st number is " << arr [0] << endl;
cout << "The 5th number is " << arr [4] << endl;
cout << "The 6th number is " << arr [5] << endl;
arr [1] = 100;
arr [9] = 1000;    
cout << "The 2nd number is " << arr [1] << endl;
cout << "The last element is " << arr [9] << endl;

How can I initialize all elements in the array at once?
I thought if I just keep {}, all the elements in the array will be initialized to 0, but only the last number which I am displaying, in this case "The 6th number", is getting initialized to 0.

How many is "all"? You haven't told the compiler how many elements you want the array to have. Unlike some other languages, it won't be sized or resized dynamically; the size must be given in the declaration and cannot change after that.

int arr [10] {}; should work as you expect. The code as you have it should not compile like that

Please use warnings as errors. Add compilation flags -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror for gcc or clang and /W4 /WX for MSVC. Compiler will catch for you lots of common beginner mistakes. https://godbolt.org/z/jf1rTGfMW

int arr [] {}; No do NOT do this if you know your array size at compile time use std::array, otherwise use std::vector. These types will always know how many elements they contain (and can be returned from functions without creating a lot of memory managment headaches)

You have caused a potential crash. int arr [] {}; reserves 0 bytes on the stack for the table, so any operation overwrites or reads the next variables.
https://godbolt.org/z/bo7jbEso7
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int arr [] {};
    int test = 1234;
    int test2 = 5678;

    std::cout << "The 0 number is " << arr [0] << std::endl; // The 0 number is 5678
    std::cout << "The 1 number is " << arr [1] << std::endl; // The 1 number is 1234

}

However, following code prints 10, as you probably expected:
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int arr [] {10, 10};
    int test = 1234;
    int test2 = 5678;

    std::cout << "The 0 number is " << arr [0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The 1 number is " << arr [1] << std::endl;

}


Technically, the original code has Undefined Behavior, so anything can happen. A crash in not guaranteed.
